# How to set up repository to version different directories

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm wondering how to go about versioning different directories on my system that can't really sit in one central project/trunk/ directory.

That is, I'm working on a client server with web frontend project that uses Bitbake.  The server portion of the code sits in a Bitbake directory, the client portion sits on a directory in my /home/ directory, and the server stuff sits in /srv/html/myproject.

I would like all three parts of the code to sit in the repo at /home/project/trunk.  What's the best way to do this?

Right now, I'm just hardlinking all my directories to /home/project/trunk, but I'm not sure if it's too hacky.

Any best practices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the 3 directories under /home/project/trunk, and add that to source control. Then write a script that copies or export the relevant files where you want them to end up. Call this script every time you want to do a deploy.